# Angular 2 Binding em Component

Tags: angular, binding, componentes

Tenho o seguinte cenário.

Possuo uma lista em um *webservice*, porém quando eu espero um retorno para passar o valor para meu componente, ele simplesmente não faz o *binding* porque é demorado, e mesmo quando traz, caso eu chame o *WS* novamente, ele não atualiza os dados.

Segue abaixo código de como estou tentando implementar. Eu fiz esse exemplo por cima sem colocar os `imports`, só para colocar aqui e expor a maneira que estou tentando implementar.

```
@Component({
    template:'<div *ngFor="let dados of lista">{{dados.nome}}<br/></div>',
    selector: 'meu-component'
})
MeuComponent {
    private _vaiPraView: any;
    @Input() testes: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.trataDados();
    }

    trataDados () {
        this._vaiPraView = [];
        let idx = 0;
        for(let teste of this.testes) {
            teste.realvector = idx;
            idx++;
            this._vaiPraView.push(teste);
        }
    }
}

//html... com binding (não rola...)
@Component({
    template:'<meu-component [testes]="lista"></meu-component>',
    directives: [MeuComponent]
})
export class TestePage {
    private lista: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit () {
        //Um evento demorado.. formato de data exemplo: [{nome: 'oi'},{nome: 'tudobem'},{nome: 'contigo'}]
        AlgumaCoisa.then(data => {
            this.lista = data;
        });
    }
}

//html... sem binding rola porém quero que fique do jeito acima e detecte a alteração.
@Component({
    template:'<meu-component [testes]="[{nome: 'oi'},{nome: 'tudobem'},{nome: 'contigo'}]"></meu-component>',
    directives: [MeuComponent]
})
export class TestePage {
    private lista: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit () {
        //Um evento demorado.. formato de data exemplo: [{nome: 'oi'},{nome: 'tudobem'},{nome: 'contigo'}]
        AlgumaCoisa.then(data => {
            this.lista = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Na primeira parte ali `MeuComponent { ...` você não usou o `export class`, será que o problema poderia ser ali?

Comment: Não acredito que fosse isso @wdarking ... Nossa quanto tempo essa pergunta rs... Era iniciando no angular ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Voce precisa chamar a função `trataDados()` no ngOnChange para atualizar o campo `lista` do componente `MeuComponent` quando o input `testes` for atualizado.

Answer (score 0):

O certo seria usar uma variável do tipo Observable... e nela utilizar o método subscribe... isso garante que será executado após o retorno...

```
metodo.subscribe(result => {
   this.lista = result.json();
   console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifica o primeiro componente pra executar a função toda vez que "receber" novos dados você pode fazer dessa maneira

```
@Component({
    template:'<div *ngFor="let dados of lista">{{dados.nome}}<br/></div>',
    selector: 'meu-component'
})
MeuComponent {
    private _vaiPraView: any;
    @Input() testes: any;

    
    @Input('testes')
    set name(testes: any[]) {        
        this._vaiPraView = [];
        let idx = 0;
        for(let teste of testes) {
            teste.realvector = idx;
            idx++;
            this._vaiPraView.push(teste);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que o tratarDados só executa uma vez no OnInit do Component. Então precisamos executar o tratar dados logo após obter os dados para resolver o problema.

Em **meu-component.ts**

1. Troque o ngOnInit por **ngOnChanges**, assim quando a resposta da requisição terminar ele irá alterar o array e atualizar o component.

```
     export class MeuComponentComponent implements OnChanges {
   
     ngOnChanges(){
       this.trataDados();
     }
```

2. Retire o private da propriedade **_vaiPraView** para ela estar acessível no template (meu-component.html)

```
    _vaiPraView: any;
```

Em **test-page.component.ts**

1. Retire o private da propriedade **lista**

*Dicas*

- Evite erro caso os dados ainda não estejam prontos

```
trataDados () {
    if(!this.testes || this.testes.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
```

*Referencia:*

- Documentação Oficial do OnChanges
  https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges
- Sobre acessar propriedades privadas dentro do template
  https://medium.com/@erVikas1/angular-and-typescript-public-properties-a5a3c363b790
  https://github.com/devoto13/angular2-private-members-example

Answer (score 0):

### Crie um Componente Reativo

Para obter uma melhor performance transforme seu componente em um componente reativo com `rxjs`.

Uma boa pratica ao utilizar `Observables` e usar o pipe `async` do angular pois evita erros de memory leak.

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, map } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'meu-component',
  template:'<div *ngFor="let dados of vaiPraViewList$ | async">{{dados.nome}}<br/></div>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MeuComponent {

  public testes$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  @Input() private set testes(testes: any[]) {
    this.testes$.next(testes);
  }

  public get vaiPraViewList$() {
    return this.testes$.pipe(
      map((testes) => {
        return testes.map((item, index) => {
          item.realvector = index;
          return item;
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```